# QProgressBar (Qt 5.4.0) produces black blank screen

Tags: qt, qprogressbar

I wanted to use a `QProgressBar` in the following function:

```
void InstallingWindow::install_package(QString pkgname, QString tempdir){

    qDebug() << "Imported tempdir is " + tempdir;

    QFile ee_script("/usr/bin/ee_script");

    QString program_install = "sudo /usr/bin/ee_script " + pkgname + " " + tempdir + " install";

    if (!ee_script.exists()){
        qDebug() << "Install script does not exists";
        ee_script.error();
    }
    else{
        process_install->start(program_install);
        ui->progressBar->setMinimum(0);
        ui->progressBar->setMaximum(0);

        connect(process_install, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), ui->progressBar, SLOT(show_progress_bar()));  
        process_install->waitForFinished(-1); //this will make the screen blank

    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(0);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(100);

        ui->nextButton->setEnabled(true);

    }
    post_install();

}

void InstallingWindow::show_progress_bar(){

    ui->progressBar->setMaximum(100);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(100);
    ui->nextButton->setEnabled(true);

}
```

I wanted progress bar to work as a wait bar (initially; later will be implemented with timer) and completed (finished at 100) after the `QProcess` finished.  I get a blank black screen with `process_install->waitForFinished(-1)`.
I tried many options but all in vain, while `QProgressDialog` works fine. Kindly help me where is the fault and what could I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `waitForFinished`, you are blocking the GUI thread, so the progress dialog never gets events, and so never paints.  You'll need to arrange for the event loop to run regularly - something like (untested):

```
process_install->start(program_install);

do {
    qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
} while (process_install->waitForFinished(20)); //  1/50 second

ui->nextButton->setEnabled(true);
```

BTW, it's good idea to `connect(process_install, SIGNAL(...), ...)` **before** `process_install->start`, to avoid race conditions.  Unlikely with a process that needs a progress meter, but still a good habit to get into.  :-)

Comment: Sir, the problem is with (-1) if I use other time values (1,2,3...) then it works fine. But I wanted that when the QProcess finished than the next instruction to be executed, which I think only possible with (-1).

Comment: Yes, that's why my fragment above repeatedly waits for finished, until it returns true (meaning that the process *has* finished).  Whenever it returns false, it processes events and goes back to waiting.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, solved my problem. Now QProgressbar works fine.